# Problem executing batch file Mysql

Tags: mysql

I' experiencing problems while trying to run a batch file within Mysql shell.

I wrote a stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS creaFornitori_prova$$
CREATE PROCEDURE creaFornitori_prova ()
BEGIN
create table Fornitori_prova (id_For mediumint(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
nome_For varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ind_For varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id_For)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I called the file : st_F.sql

Whenever I try to execute the file through the command : `source st_F.sql;`

I get this error:

ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'st_F.sql', error: 2

I get the same error when I use `\. st_Fornitori.sql;`

Thanks Mauro

Answer (score 1):

```
source DRIVE:ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO/st_F.sql;
```

Comment: Thanks I moved to where st_F.sql is located and run the command above and everything is ok...